# What does cpg mean during OpenBSD install at disk partition?

Tags: openbsd

What does cpg mean during OpenBSD install at disk partition?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cpg is "cylinders per group". You can see more terminology in the [man page of fs](https://man.openbsd.org/fs).